# How to get larger icons in gridview for tablet

Tags: android

I made a layout with a gridview for small screens (2.7 inch). My icons are 48 x 48 px. Now i want the gridview on a tablet so i created a new layout and changed the settings to large and landscape. I want to use larger icons for the tablet: 72 x 72 px. The problem is that the larger icons not showing up but the small icons does. My small icons are in the folder drawable-mdpi and the large icons are in the folder drawable-hdpi. I tried allready to move the large icons to the drawable-xhdpi folder but without success. I also tried to change the scaletype and the layoutparams of the imageadapter but also without any success Can someone help me to get the larger icons on the tablet?

Here is my code of the large layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back" >



<GridView
    android:id="@+id/Menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:horizontalSpacing="130dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="50dp" android:layout_marginTop="50dip">

</GridView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code of my imageadapter for the gridview is:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return menu_icon.length;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));                 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(menu_icon[position]);
        return imageView;


    }
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to show icon based on device's screen size, automatically?

Comment: yes, thats the point :-)

Comment: put your images in drawable-large for 7inch tablet(samsung tablet) & drawable-xhdpi for 10inch tablet(motorola xoom)

Comment: @ Android Coader: I allready did that but for some reason the large layout don't look in the drawable-hdpi. I don't have a drawable-large folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

This may work.

Comment: did you put that line before imageView.setImageResource(menu_icon[position]); ?

Comment: menu_icon[position] what is this? is it an array of image(drawable ids)

Comment: yes, i created this array at the beginning of my java code. I did this for the icons and for the text under the icons.

Comment: Maybe is it because i put the arrays before the oncreate method?

Comment: might be, over optimization is problem sometime,:)

Comment: Now i have them in my onCreate method but it is the same. First i thought that a larger layout automaticaly will use the items from the drawable folder that suites them.

Comment: yes thats how it is supposed to work don't know whats going wrong, re visit your code once there might be some silly mistake that you are doing

Comment: I found the solution :-). First i created a new layout with the setting: Size: large and Orientation: Landscape. I solved this by adding the setting "Density: Medium". Then it creates a folder called drawable-large-land-mdpi. Then insert all the images that suites the large layout.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html